# Return and save 800 friend's tweets using Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to extract the tweets of my friends using api.home_timeline. I don't want to stream it, but I want to save 800 tweets, the screen names, and their likes/favorites count to a csv file. Twitter only allows 200 tweets at a time. Given my keys as already specified, this is what I have so far:

```
 def data_set(handle):
    auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth=set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
    api=tweepy.API(auth)
    count_tweets=api.home_timeline(screen_name=handle,count=200)
    twits=[]
    tweet_data=[tweet.text for tweet in count_tweets]

    for t in count_tweets:
       twits.append(t)

if __name__== '__main__':
tweet_data('my twitter name')
```

my original plan was to have multiple count_tweets such as count_tweet1, etc. I am unsure how to proceed with the rest. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter follows [pagination](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/guides/pagination.html). For every request, you make it gives a maximum of 200 tweets(in the case of [home_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline)). The 200 tweets you get are based on popularity. You can fetch all the tweets from the user's timeline by iterating over the pages. Tweepy provides `Cursor` functionality to iterate over the pages

Edited code for your case:

```
def data_set(handle):
    auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth=set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
    api=tweepy.API(auth)
    tweet_data = []
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=handle, count=200, tweet_mode='extended').pages():
        for tweet in page:
            tweet_data.append(tweet.full_text)
    return tweet_data

## Not sure why the following lines are needed
#    twits=[]
#    tweet_data=[tweet.text for tweet in count_tweets]

#    for t in count_tweets:
#        twits.append(t)

if __name__== '__main__':
    print(data_set('my twitter name'))
```

I have used `api.user_timeline` instead of `api.home_timeline` in the code as you said you are trying to fetch the tweets from your friends timeline. If your use case is satisfied by `api.home_timeline` you can replace it instead.